# How to get the width of an element that breaks out of its container with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I want to make a small plugin for WordPress that checks if any title breaks out of its container and the font-size should be edited.

My PHP goes trough all the titles of every page and every article. It then takes each word out of the titles and puts them into an array. It then checks the longest individual word on all the titles and echoes it out.

I then want to use javascript to alert if the longest word in the website does not fit in its container so I can use responsive design and insert correct font-sizes for all window sizes.

This is my PHP (It works but I'm a designer so this is probably garbage. You can suggest still suggest improvements of course):

```
$all = array();

// posts
$custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=-999999'); 
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); 
$title  = get_the_title();
$pieces = explode(" ", $title);
$all = array_merge($pieces, $all);
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

//pages
query_posts( 'post_type=page&posts_per_page=999999999' ); 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
$title  = get_the_title();
$pieces = explode(" ", $title);
$all = array_merge($pieces, $all);
endwhile; 
endif; 

$lengths = array_map('strlen', $all);
$maxLength = max($lengths);
$index = array_search($maxLength, $lengths);
$longestHeading = $all[$index];

echo "<h1>" .  $longestHeading . "</h1>";
```

The width of the heading is equal to its container although it breaks out. I'd like to know if it breaks out and is longer than the container and then alert the user.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the real value of the `h1` you need to add two properties:

```
div{
  width:300px;
  border:1px dashed grey;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Add `nowrap` to avoid the title break in lines. And:

```
h1 {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Add `inline-block` to break the block state of the h1 keeping the width of his content.

Check the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lubwH)

Comment: The `white-space:nowrap;` declaration can actually be added to the `h1` element instead.

Comment: Nice one! Thank you Danko. For some reason I have never used the CSS white-space property before.

Comment: This is only part of the solution, as the container of the h1 should not be "overflow: hidden", or the real width calculated by JS will not be the total real size.